# how to refresh Material Spinner in activity?

Tags: java, android

Using API through I was adding data in spinner that are added but that are not displayed in spinner at a time, so how can I refresh activity and newly added data to show at a time? i can used this link ....https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner/blob/master/README.md

```
       (Schoolschool:userDetails.getSchools()) {
        schoolList.add(school.getSchoolName());}

        schoolDropDown.setItems(schoolList);
        schoolDropDown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Make sure you have add `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` in code.

Comment: @nidhi93 first find listview used in schoolDropDown and get the adapter from that list and make notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: @nidhi93 In MaterialSpinner.java they used listview to show content.

Comment: @nidhi93 still have problem ?

Comment: I have only used the gridle that and implement that any java file not added.

Comment: see this link https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/jaredrummler/materialspinner

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I am using this link refrence..........

https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner/blob/master/README.md

Comment: You should attached the data to spinner using adapter

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Adapter using `setAdapter(...)`, for the `Spinner`, too. This defines the layout to be used for each individual item. i.e.

```
schoolDropDown.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, schoolList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call setAdapter() once and you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to update the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(frgmActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listCityNames);
   cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spCitys.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
```

Or 
Try below two lines :

```
String[] schoolsArr = schoolList.toArray(new String[schoolList.size()]);
schoolDropDown.setItems(schoolsArr);
```

Instead of this line: `schoolDropDown.setItems(schoolList);`

Comment: Put this code in function and call that function after every updated data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set adapter to the spinner for displaying data

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, schoolList);  
   dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

schoolDropDown.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

After data change you need to call

dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();